# QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [Deactivated]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am trying to use enum in jqp query but getting error

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [Deactivated]
```

here is my code

```
import com.uzzz.enums.DStateEnum;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Query("SELECT dlCode FROM GDETable WHERE d.Id = ?1 AND d.dState.state <> :Deactivated")
List<String> findAllDsCodeExcludingDeactivatedById(Integer Id);
```

how to fix this issue?

here is DStateEnum.java

```
public enum DStateEnum {

    Cancelled("Cancelled"),
    Active("Active"),
    Paused("Paused"),
    Deactivated("Deactivated");

    private DStateEnum(final String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static DStateEnum fromString(String text) {
        if (text != null) {
            for (DStateEnum b : DStateEnum.values()) {
                if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(b.getName())) {
                    return b;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, and where in your code you fill parameter `Deactivated`?

Comment: its from import com.uzzz.enums.DStateEnum

Comment: really? how? Never heard about such `import` operator feature.

Comment: code added for DStateEnum

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple things wrong with the query method definition:

1. You cannot mix and match ordinal parameters and named ones. You either need to go `?1` and `?2` or come up with a name for `?1`.
2. You need to provide parameters for both placeholders in the method signature. So as you don't pipe anything into the method for `:Description`, Spring Data will not be able to bind it to the query (how should it do?).

Answer (score 0):

You have a [named parameter](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/) in your query called `:Deactivated` that hasn't been given a value.

I'm not too familiar with the @Query annotation, but it looks to me that you have only supplied the "id" value and not the "state" one in your method. You will either need to pass in the ":Deactivated" named parameter or replace it with a fixed value.